# iphone UIImagePicker controller can not decode message

Tags: iphone, swift

I am trying to select a video file from gallery by UIImagePicker controller but when i have select this file it is showing "Can not Decode" message (I am using KTypeMovie in image picker controller and it is working some video files fine).

Please suggest how can i resolved it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error because the video file is not in a supported format.

All your video files should use a format that is compatible with Apple iTunes, such as an MP4 file with h.264 encoding.

If your video does not play properly in the viewer, re-encode the video to .mp4 h.264 using **[Adobe Media Encoder](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwjn9qbmvJHGAhUDJ6YKHTGfAHc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fsupport%2Fdownloads%2Fproduct.jsp%3Fplatform%3DWindows%26product%3D160&ei=zqZ-VefXM4POmAWxvoK4Bw&usg=AFQjCNG5wnrW8RLhK9cgEqMALiQ59yB7sg)** or a third-party tool such as [**Handbrake**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwju35nHvJHGAhWBMqYKHd1wADg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhandbrake.fr%2F&ei=jaZ-Va7lJYHlmAXd4YHAAw&usg=AFQjCNEd0aj1cRaPX6hc3cAY2NEAj3scjA&bvm=bv.95515949,d.dGY).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i can play this video on any browser or same in android app. it is not playing only in iOS

Comment: then as I mentioned, re-encode the video to .mp4 h.264 using Adobe Media Encoder or a third-party tool such as Handbrake.